# What is the density function of a random variable $X\chi_E$?

Tags: probability

Assume that $X$ is a random variable of the continuous type on a probabilistic space $(\Omega, {\cal S},P)$ with density function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and let $E\in {\cal S}$.
Is then (or when is) the random variable $X\chi_E$ (the product of $X$ and the indicator function of the set $E$) of continuous type and with what a density function?

Comment: Only if P(E)=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\Chi{{\raise{0.5ex}{\chi}}}$If $\mathbb P(E)=1$, then it is clear that $X\Chi_E$ has the same distribution as $X$, and so is a continuous random variable.

If $\mathbb P(E)<1$, then $$\mathbb P(X\Chi_E{=}0)~=~1-\mathbb P(E)~>~0,$$ hence $X\Chi_E$ is not a continuous random variable.